# Active directory home folder misreporting its used space on Windows 10 client

Tags: windows-10, active-directory, quota

The server shows the actual used space (a few KB) but the users Windows 10 desktop shows they have used 4.99 GB of their 5 GB quota and won't allow them to save anything. How do I force Windows 10 re-evaluate the used space?

Comment: You say the server shows the used space as only a few KB, but you claim the desktop shows they are using 4.99 GB out of 5 GB, a difference of only a few KB.  Are you sure your not simply not reading the server data wrong?

Comment: The server doesn't say a few KB left it says a few KB used. Also if you open the home folder on the Windows 10 desktop, select all, and look at the properties it also indicates the files there are only taking up a few KB

Comment: I know what you said it says, I was suggesting, that perhaps based on the behavior you were reporting you were miss interrupting what was being reported.